# Cython: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, cython

`cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -ID:\CodeProjects\pandasproject\envs\one\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\sonu\m
iniconda2\include -ID:\CodeProjects\pandasproject\envs\one\PC /Tcpandas\_libs\groupby.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pandas\_libs\groupby.obj
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory`

The solutions already on SO are not helping much. After this problem, I got a new VS distribution and had put the folder having the cl.exe into the PATH. Still it's not helping. For additional info, it all started with upgrading to PyCharm 2017 though I don't know what role it plays here.

Comment: *put the folder having the cl.exe into the PATH* that's not how to do this (moreover, it creates a total mess: what if you want to use multiple versions of VS?). Start by running your VS version's dev command prompt which will set *all* needed variables automatically, then run whatever build command. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Which version of python environment are you using, 3.6 or 3.5?